# Vuejs update parent component data from extended component events

Tags: vue.js

I am authoring a dashboard in Vue.js and Vuetify.

The dashboard will be composed by a grid of widgets that all have the same header and footer with different content (most of them are charts).

I am using `extend` feature of Vue.js to create a standard widget that will be inherited by all the other final widgets.

Unfortunately I am not able to set the title of the base widget from the main view that hosts an instance of the derived component.

Let me show you an extremely simplified example of what I am trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/b1gvnfdh/25/

The "Default" user never gets updated when I type a new username in the text field.

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

Here, you're getting a value of `title` from `parent` components. Hence you need to get it from Parent component.

You can use `$parent` before title to get the value of the title.

Here is the link to working [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/varit05/t9L7y0z8/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your solution works, I am wondering why I could not find any reference to this behavior in Vue.js docs